# How to model a recursive probabilistic experiment?

Tags: probability, distributions, poisson-binomial-distribution, recursive-model

I have a theoretical experiment as follows:

We have two boxes A and B, and N unfair coins (each has different probability for showing Heads).

At the beginning, box A contains all N coins and box B is empty.
the experiment includes following ordered steps:

- Step 1: move M coins from box A to box B. The chosen coins must be Heads and have the biggest probabilities for showing Heads.
- Step 2: shake both boxes.
- Step 3: check box B and return all Tails back to box A.
- Step 4: go to (Step 1).

Now the question is, How to measure coins count in box B?

Can we provide a probabilistic measurement that tells how would we be close to (or far from) a specific desired count D?

and how many repeats do need for that?

Comment: any suggestions!!?

Answer (score 1):

1) It's unclear why do we need to shake both boxes as Step 2. Based on the description, we move coins from A to B based on their probabilities of showing Heads, while we move coins from B to A based on the experimental result from Step 2. Thus, it's sufficient to shake B only. Is this correct?

2) Nevertheless, assuming I understand the setting correctly, the answer depends on the distribution of "unfairness" in your N coins. Can we assume they can be unfair to any extent, i.e. the probability for showing Heads can be any number in $(0;1)$? If yes, we could model this probability itself as a $(0;1)$-uniformly distributed variable and move forward with order statistics analysis. If no, there should be some additional condition on how unfair a coin could be, say, $0.4<=p<=0.6$ or something.

UPD

Based on your comment, the iterative process is "skewed": at each experimental iteration we move **not more than M Heads** coins form A to B and **all Tail** coins from B to A. Based on how the known probabilities $0<p_{(1)}<=p_{(2)}<=...<=p_{(N)}<1$ were initially obtained, this iterative process can either converge or not.

Here we are with a little simulation code for **uniformly drawn** $p_j$ (which are assumed to be known in your setting, of course):

```
N = 100
M = 20

p = sort(runif(N)) # uniformly distributed unfairness in coins

p.A = p[1:(N-M)] # box A contains all but M coins with largest Heads probability
p.B = p[(N-M+1):N]

BernoulliExperiment = function(prob){runif(1)<prob}

n.iter = 10000

n.A = integer(n.iter) # number of coins in box A
n.B = integer(n.iter) # number of coins in box B

for(iter in 1:n.iter){
    A2B = apply(as.data.frame(p.A),1,BernoulliExperiment)
    if(sum(A2B)>M)
        A2B[which(A2B)[1:(sum(A2B)-M)]] = FALSE

    B2A = !apply(as.data.frame(p.B),1,BernoulliExperiment)

    temp = p.A[A2B]
    p.A = sort(c(p.A[!A2B],p.B[B2A]))
    p.B = sort(c(p.B[!B2A],temp))
    rm(temp)

    n.A[iter] = length(p.A)
    n.B[iter] = length(p.B)
}

plot(n.A, type='l')
plot(n.B, type='l')
```

The process is **balanced on average** but **no specific count is the limit** for the number of coins in B. Thus, any number of repeats is insufficient for coming closer to the desired count.

On the other hand, a bimodal distribution of $p_j$ (say, all $p_j$ equal either to 0.1 or 0.9 as an extreme discrete case) could lead to a convergent process of separation into two subsets of coins. This idea comes from Order Statistics by David & Nagaraya, Chapter 8 (https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/0471722162)

Comment: 1) Shaking A and B only means that all coins' statuses keep changing based on their probabilities, inside both A and B.
2) I started by assuming that the N probabilities are known, 0 <= p0 <= p1  <= ... <= pN <= 1

Comment: Thank you very much, (and sorry no sufficient reputation to top up the answer). I'm very interested about the conclusion **any number of repeats is insufficient for coming closer to the desired count**, can we derive a proof or a probability inequality to describe such statement?